# Why does this Factory's property not work?

Tags: angularjs

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/43zo9fsp/3/)

```
{{Data.x}} does not work. 5 does not display.
{{Data.y.prop1}} works. 6 is displayed
```

Why is that ? Whats the difference in the way the two properties are referenced ?

Comment: Code in the question and in the fiddle defers. So its unclear what you're asking really. Always try to include relevance code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{Data.y.prop1}}
```

`Data.y` has a sub property which is `prop1` and it contain a value which is `6`

```
 {{Data.x}}
```

In this case `Data.x` either doesn't have a value at all OR it has a sub property which contains the value like in above mentioned example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your assigning to the wrong variable. You want to change `Trade` but you assigned it to the local variable `obj`.

```
obj = {
    x: a,
    y: b
}
```

This should be changed as:

```
this.Trade = {
   x: a,
   y: b
}
```

or

```
this.Trade.x = a;
this.Trade.x = b;
```

If you wanna know why it worked in `y`, refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) accepted answer for it will give you a clear answer.